# Adding a usercontrol dynamically to an updatepanel

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, user-controls, updatepanel

I've got a page with an updatePanel....

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="up1_Load">
  <ContentTemplate>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've also got a usercontrol (vastly simplified here for the purposes of this example)...

**UserControl Markup:**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="CtlParts.ascx.vb" Inherits="myProj.myProj.UserControls.ctlParts" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"%>  
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="txtTest"></asp:textbox>
```

I am trying to dynamically add the usercontrol to the update panel ([following this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.contenttemplatecontainer.aspx)) ....

**Form VB**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ctl As New UserControls.ctlParts
    ctl.ID = "ctlParts1"
    up1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(ctl)
End Sub
```

It appears to work, as there are no errors, and I can access the usercontrol itself in the load event of the update panel....

**Form VB**

```
Public Sub up1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
Handles up1.Load  
         'Finds this control ok
         Dim ctl As UserControls.ctlParts = DirectCast(sender, System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel).FindControl("ctlParts1") 
         ctl.getTextBoxContent()    
    End Sub
```

However, I can't access any of the controls on the usercontrol.....

**Usercontrol VB**:

```
Public Sub getTextBoxContent()
    return txtTest.text 'This throws an error- txtTest is nothing
End Sub
```

Anyone got any ideas why this is happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

You need to use the [LoadControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) Method. So, in the Page_Load:

```
Dim ctl As UserControls.ctlParts=CType(LoadControl("ctlParts.ascx"), ctlParts)
```

(Hope this helps someone.)